# Left Join Show All Rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

```
SELECT 
    CH.ChannelName, COUNT(O.OrderID) AS Orders
FROM
    Channels CH
LEFT JOIN Programs P USING (ChannelID)
LEFT JOIN Codes C USING (ProgramID)
LEFT JOIN Order O USING (CodeID)
WHERE
    O.OrderDate = '2012-04-11'
GROUP BY 
    CH.ChannelName
WITH ROLLUP
```

This query is only returning channels that have orders. How do I display ALL channels, even if there are no orders in the order table for that particular channel? So basically, all channels will be listed, and if there are no orders for that channel, I need to display zero.

I know the solution to this is probably very simple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your where-clause limits the query to the channels that have orders for that date, but if you move that condition into the join statement it will give you the result you want:

```
SELECT 
    CH.ChannelName, COUNT(O.ID) AS Orders
FROM
    Channels CH
LEFT JOIN Programs P USING (ChannelID)
LEFT JOIN Codes C USING (ProgramID)
LEFT JOIN Order O ON CH.CodeID = O.CodeID AND O.OrderDate = '2012-04-11'
GROUP BY 
    CH.ChannelName
WITH ROLLUP
```

Note, that it should be `COUNT(O.ID)` to make SQL count only rows with non-null orders. In that case you'll correctly get zero orders count for channels without orders.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CH.ChannelName, COUNT(O.OrderID) AS Orders
FROM
    Channels CH
LEFT JOIN Programs P USING (ChannelID)
LEFT JOIN Codes C USING (ProgramID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order O USING (CodeID)
WHERE
    O.OrderDate = '2012-04-11'
GROUP BY 
    CH.ChannelName
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Outer join won't help in that case. It'll only add rows for orders that have no corresponding channel, but that's not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CH.ChannelName, SUM(O.OrderDate = '2012-04-11') AS Orders
FROM Channels CH
LEFT JOIN Programs P USING (ChannelID)
LEFT JOIN Codes C USING (ProgramID)
LEFT JOIN Order O USING (CodeID)
GROUP BY CH.ChannelName
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Suppose you have a channel that has only one order on some other date, let's say on 2012-12-12. After the join there'll be only one row for that channel and it'll have 2012-12-12 in the `OrderDate` column. Then your where-clause will filter this row out and the resulting table won't contain that channel at all. Am I right?

Comment: Nice, that should work. But if you think of performance I'd expect moving this condition into the join statement make it a bit faster as we get a smaller set of rows after joining the tables.

Comment: @KL-7 Actually, we don't get a smaller set of rows as it is a left join.

Comment: Hm, don't we? With `O.OrderDate = '2012-04-11'` in the join statement we filter out a whole bunch of rows from order table leaving only those that we're going to count and removing all all orders for other dates. What left join does is just adding one nullified row for channels that don't have any orders at all (or any orders on that date if you add this condition into the join statement).

Comment: @KL-7 Left join will additionally return all matched rows on the first condition and will put null values for the ones that don't match the second one. That will result on the same amount of rows. I can't think of a dataset which would return less rows putting a condnition like that in the left join :(

Comment: If you have a channel with one order on `2012-04-11` and a thousand of orders on other dates left join without condition on date will return a table with 1001 rows, then you'll go over this table of 1001 rows counting rows with date equal to `2012-04-11`. On the other hand if you add date condition into the join statement left join will return a table with a single row (that will have `2012-04-11` in the `OrderDate` column). That means sum statement will iterate only over a small table of one row to count orders for that channel and date.

Comment: @KL-7 I still don't agree :( I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa257/1) for you to see why this doesn't seem to be correct. Feel free to update it and send it back to me so I can check what you're saying.

Comment: I'm afraid we might be talking about different things, but [that's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/566f6/4) what I meant. Without condition you get a lot of additional rows that you're not going to count anyway.

Comment: @KL-7 Oh, you've removed the primary key from the orders table. We're understanding the model and how data is organized in different ways. Anyway, I agree with you on the fact that if data is organized the way you understood the problem, indeed it'll run faster.